# excel statistics appearances or delays of a value

Tags: excel

I have a big excel doc with 30 columns and more than 70.000 rows and i want stats for a specific column. This column has only two values "O" and "U" letters. Is it possible to have statistics for consecutive appearances of "O" and "U" or how many times it delays to appear? (example:how many times value "O" appears after 7 cells of "U").Is it possible to search in this column for a sequence of values (example : how many times the sequence "U,U,O,O,U" appears in the column? If these are not possible with excel which software should I use?

Comment: These are possible - what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way I can think is tow more columns. One for O and one for U.

**Column 0**

You would check in every row if value is O you would add 1 to the number from the above row. If it isn't O you would set it zero to start again.

**Column U**

The same thing as above.

This way the max of column 0 would be the maximun straight appearances of 0 and delay of U. The same for the other column.

Programmatically you could do it in so many languages. Just by putting the values next to each other you get any of the information you want. For the max appearances and delays the logic I would think would be similar to the above. For the sequence though it would be really easier to just look for this string into a concatenated string of all the values.